# Correlating JSON Response Body in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

I tried to design a test script of API Load Testing in JMeter 5.0. Here is my thread group info:

[image]

Below is the Body Data, I already added some variables and functions to it. You can also view the sample JSON Body Data at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mfNh3NwMV6G1vQY_-xvYOWogP6LhkPwA/view?usp=sharing):

```
    {
    "app_name": "Telekom",
    "source": "MOENGAGE",
    "moe_request_id": "req_${__threadNum}",
    "events": [
        {
            "event_name": "Email Opened",
            "event_code": "MOE_EMAIL_OPEN",
            "event_uuid": "${__UUID}",
            "event_time": ${__jexl3(${__time(,)}/1000,)},
            "event_type": "CAMPAIGN_EVENT",
            "event_source": "MOENGAGE",
            "uid": "${__counter(,)}-${__RandomString(7,ABCDEFG123456)}${uid}",
            "email_id": "${email}",
            "event_attributes": {
                "campaign_id": "${__RandomString(24,abcdefghijklmn123456789)}",
                "campaign_name": "July2021_16072021_LigaSuper_English",
                "campaign_type": "GENERAL",
                "campaign_channel": "EMAIL",
                "moe_delivery_type": "One Time",
                "moe_campaign_tags": [
                    "engagement"
                ],
                "moe_campaign_channel": "Email",
                "u_em": "${email}"
            },
            "user_attributes": {
                "PRODUCT_TYPE": "Unifi",
                "moengage_user_id": "60dc48d4d722040a2e78b788",
                "SERVICE_NO": "${uid}",
                "id": "${email}"
            },
            "device_attributes": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

I also include JSON Extractor to do correlation on the response body:

[image]

Here is the results in View Results Tree. Added Debug Sampler to see the whether my parameterization and correlation working or not. Fortunately, only my parameterization is working, while correlation is not.

[image]

**Updated**: This is example of response body:

[image]

I want to correlate at `"rqUuid": "urn:uuid:1a5d8617-258c-49f7-b1a7-5b8ee71fb9fd"` in the response body. Question is, is this the correct way to correlate the JSON Body? Do I need to correlate the response body although I already define the function `"event_uuid": "${__UUID}"` in the Body Data?

Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) for extracting values from JSON responses.

Your JSON path expression should be  `responseHeader.rqUuid`

[image]

You can evaluate the JSON Path expressions or JMESPath expression through the View Result tree or with online tools.

1. View Result Tree
   [image]
2. You can generate the expressions online with http://jsonselector.com/
3. JMSE Path Evaluator https://jmespath.org

Sample JMX is uploaded to GitHub for your reference https://github.com/pragmatictesters/Pragmatic-Learning-JMeter-Examples/blob/master/TestPlan-StackOverFlow-68706730-JSON.jmx

Comment: Please refer to updated question, I include the response body screenshot as well. I just want to extract `"rqUuid"` in `"responseHeader"` array (Response body). Please advise

Comment: Updated the answer and uploaded a sample JMX [Link] (https://github.com/pragmatictesters/Pragmatic-Learning-JMeter-Examples/blob/master/TestPlan-StackOverFlow-68706730-JSON.jmx)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a regular expression to get your data from a JSON response using the JSON Extractor. You need to use JSON Path Expressions instead of using regular expressions.

If you want to extract `event_uuid` from the response, your json path expressions would be `events[*].event_uuid`

To get the first `event_uuid` of your `events` array objects, you can use
`events[0].event_uuid`

Comment: Please refer to updated question, I include the response body screenshot as well. I just want to extract `"rqUuid"` in `"responseHeader"` array (Response body). Please advise. Still need to use JSON extractor?

Comment: if you want to extract the `rqUuid` from the response using a JSON extractor then your path expressions would be `.rqUuid`

Comment: i've tried that but not working. UUID not found

Comment: use `responseHeader.rqUuid`

Answer (score 0):

JSON Extractor allows you executing [JsonPath queries](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and it looks like you're trying to use a [regular expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) there, it will result into a syntax error, you can see [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for details:

[image]

You're showing us request data and asking about extracting values from the response, in order to be able to help we need to see at least partial (or better full) response data and what part of it do you need.

So far I can only give the following piece of advice: switch to [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter) and there is a chance it will start working without any changes

Comment: I already edited my question, please review it again. I include the full response data and here, I want to correlate the `"rqUuid": "urn:uuid:fbdfb47a-9e5d-4f87-8ccd-9875f10b84ea",`

Comment: Please advise how I can apply JSON Extractor here. Thanks sir

Comment: You cannot, if you need only `fbdfb47a-9e5d-4f87-8ccd-9875f10b84ea` part - go for either [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or for the [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/), the latter one is easier to use, it works faster and consumes less resources

Comment: If need to use Regular Expression Extractor, I still need to use function at this line `"event_uuid": "${__UUID}"`, right? Or do i need to enter the default UUID as in the sample shown in the link?

Comment: I don't know, if you need to send a random GUID-like structure - go for __UUID function, if you need to use the value from the previous response - extract it using Regular Expression Extractor

Comment: If i want to send random UUID, then no need to use Regular Expression Extractor? Sorry still not clear about this

Comment: If you want to send random UUID - no need to extract anything, just use [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) right where you want to do it - it will be evaluated in the runtime. If you need to store the generated value into a variable for later re-use you can go for [__groovy() function](${__groovy(vars.put('uuid'\, UUID.randomUUID() as String); return vars.get('uuid'),)})  `${__groovy(vars.put('uuid'\, UUID.randomUUID() as String); return vars.get('uuid'),)}`. Once done you will be able to refer it as `${uuid}` where required.